# Swift - Call UIAlertContoller аrom any location

Tags: swift, alert

Сейчас `UIAlertContoller` возможно вызвать только со `ViewController` И это вызывает некие неудобства. Допустим в ответе с сервера, а они как правило отдельном файле `NSObject`, нужно вывести на экран ошибку. Хотелось бы обработать ошибку прям после ответа сервера в ``

Хотелось бы найти способ запустить `UIAlertContoller` с любого файла впрограмы.

Comment: а что это и при чем тут nsobject?

Comment: Я так понял, что автор решил поделиться своим решением на вопрос, который его долго мучал. В таком случае лучше бы нормально сформулировать вопрос и ответить на него самому, а код с решением вставить в этот ответ.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func alert(title: String? = nil, message: String? = nil)
{
  let alertController = UIAlertController(title: title, message:message, preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.Alert)
  alertController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.Default,handler: nil))

  let window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.mainScreen().bounds)
  window.rootViewController = UIViewController()
  window.makeKeyAndVisible() //The makeKeyAndVisible message makes a window key, and moves it to be in front of any other windows on its level
  window.rootViewController?.presentViewController(alertController, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

> Этот код вызовет `Alert` с любого места в программе